# Newrelic for android slow tracing

Tags: newrelic

Installed newrelic agent for android app.

First run - everything goes smooth and fast
stop app
Run again

Observe a lot of
01-14 10:28:30.317: D/com.newrelic.agent.android(23539): Registering trace of SQLiteDatabase#query with parent FragmentActivity
01-14 10:28:30.597: D/com.newrelic.agent.android(23539): Added trace 5633b89b-bdd6-4b60-b41a-bfb44effaef4 missing children: 0

A lot - seems around hundreds

Looks like newrelic trying to keep track of my app db operations - inserts, deletes etc

But it makes the app very slow on the startup

Disabled newrelic agent - back to normal. fast startup every time

Is there a way to disable DB tracing in newrelic agent?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to disable Database tracing in the New Relic for Mobile Apps Android SDK, however extreme overhead impact like this isn't normal operation. We've identified the issue and will be releasing a new version of the Android agent in the next few days.

Those who got the pre-release (including I think this person) said it resolved the problem entirely.

Comment: Fix is now in the release version: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/android